# Native webcam permissions in chrome 28

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

I have a Flash web application that asks permission for webcam and microphone through the Flash privacy dialog.

It has been working fine and still it does but now the user is asked twice for permissions. Once from the Flash Privacy dialog and another one from Chrome.

We are not using the getUserMedia function. My application is in Flash with no HTML5 implementation.

What is the reason for dispatching the native webcam permissions in chrome when the user already accepted the Flash Security dialog? Is there any way to avoid that native security dialog displayed by Chrome? What is the Flash Security Dialog covering and why the native webcam permission is also required?

Thank you guys